# How to remove quotes from data for pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a lot of `.csv` files that I need to plot. However, the numeric data comes, sometimes, among quotes or just as numbers (without the quotes).

For example

```
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
```

My question is if there is an option in `pgfplots` to pre-process the data and remove the quotes if they are present. Or it is too much trouble to do it from here (LaTeX and friends) and I should generate outside scripts to pre-process the data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after continuing searching for a solution. I found that `pgfplotstable` can ignore some characters automatically via `ignore chars` option.

My solution right now is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma, ignore chars={"}]{data.csv}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, or if it is robust. I will report back if I found some problem with it.

Comment: +1. This is also the "suggested solution" of the package. I do not expect any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to `pgfplots`, [`dataplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) can handle quotes in the CSV file. It's far more limited that `pgfplots` and if your real data is a lot larger than the data provided in your MWE it may not cope so well. However, I thought I may as well add this as a possible alternative in case it's useful.

Since `dataplot` uses `datatool` you need to first load the data before you can plot it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dataplot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLplot{data}{x=a,y=c}

\end{document}
```

You can change the default appearance using extra keys and various commands. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dataplot}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{DTLplotroundXvar}{0}% round x tic values to 0 dp
\setcounter{DTLplotroundYvar}{0}% round y tic values to 0 dp


\DTLplot{data}{colors={blue},% line colours
 x=a,% column for x values
 y=c,% column for y values
 box,% box around plot
 style=both,% lines and markers
 marks={\pgfuseplotmark{*}},% filled circle markers
 minx=0,% minimum value on x-axis
 maxx=6,% minimum value on x-axis
 miny=0,% minimum value on x-axis
 maxy=8,% maximum value on x-axis
 xticgap=1,% gap between tic marks on x-axis
 yticgap=2,% gap between tic marks on y-axis
 axes=both% both axes
 }

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of plot]

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous method: set `` \catcode`"=9 ``; safer method: remove the quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-noquote.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}\catcode`"=9
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {\jobname.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {\jobname-noquote.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Christian Feuersänger! We can use the key `ignore chars`, section 2.1 of the manual of `pgfplotstable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
"1","4","5","1"
"2","3","1","5"
"3","5","6","1"
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-noquote.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma,ignore chars={"}] {\jobname.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {\jobname-noquote.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: About removing the quotes, there is some kind of handler, or preprocessing macro that is executed in which I can do that?

Comment: @adn Not that I know.

Comment: This solution is equivalent to `ignore chars={"}` which also applies `\catcode` 9 (but only while reading the table data).