# How to import a table with scientific formating

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Here is my not working MWE. How can I import and plot the table with the scientific formating?

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data-export-scientific.csv}
"x";"y1";"y2";"y3"
"   1";"8.649e+01";"3.501e+01";"1.013e+01"
"   2";"8.597e+01";"3.672e+01";"6.306e+00"
"   3";"8.667e+01";"4.348e+01";"9.170e+00"
"   4";"8.287e+01";"4.270e+01";"1.052e+01"
"   5";"8.747e+01";"4.081e+01";"1.118e+01"
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/x/.style={string type},
                      columns/y1/.style={string type},
                      columns/y2/.style={string type},
                      columns/y3/.style={string type}]{data-export-scientific.csv}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data-export-scientific.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=blue, only marks]table[x=x, y=y1]{\myLoadedTable};   
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [According to the author of `pgfplotstable`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281794/how-to-remove-quotes-from-data-for-pgfplots#comment679289_281823), the suggested way to deal with the double quotes in your input data is to declare them with `ignore chars={"}`.
- I removed your `string type` style declarations, because all your input data is numeric.
- You need to call `\pgfplotstableread` with appropriate options (`col sep`, `ignore chars`) to parse the CSV data *before* possibly using `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to typeset the table in the document—unless you want to parse the raw data several times, but this doesn't make much sense in my humble opinion.
- I applied the following style:

  ```latex
  my numeric col/.style={
    sci, sci zerofill, sci sep align, precision=2, sci 10e
  }
  ```

  to all columns except the first one in the typeset table. This is done with:

  ```latex
  every column/.code={
    \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol>0\relax
      \pgfkeysalso{my numeric col}
    \fi
  }
  ```
- I implemented nice formatting of the table using the `booktabs` package and this styling information:

  ```latex
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
  ```
- I bumped the `pgfplots` compatibility level to 1.16 for good measure using this line:

  ```latex
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
  ```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data-export-scientific.csv}
"x";"y1";"y2";"y3"
"   1";"8.649e+01";"3.501e+01";"1.013e+01"
"   2";"8.597e+01";"3.672e+01";"6.306e+00"
"   3";"8.667e+01";"4.348e+01";"9.170e+00"
"   4";"8.287e+01";"4.270e+01";"1.052e+01"
"   5";"8.747e+01";"4.081e+01";"1.118e+01"
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, ignore chars={"}]
  {data-export-scientific.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    my numeric col/.style={
      sci, sci zerofill, sci sep align, precision=2, sci 10e
    },
    every column/.code={
      \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol>0\relax
        \pgfkeysalso{my numeric col}
      \fi
    },
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{\myLoadedTable}
  \caption{My table data}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=blue, only marks] table[x=x, y=y1] {\myLoadedTable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{My plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

As a refinement, you can even improve the table headers using LaTeX math formulas with proper subscripts based on the column numbers inside the value of `/pgfplots/table/column name`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data-export-scientific.csv}
"x";"y1";"y2";"y3"
"   1";"8.649e+01";"3.501e+01";"1.013e+01"
"   2";"8.597e+01";"3.672e+01";"6.306e+00"
"   3";"8.667e+01";"4.348e+01";"9.170e+00"
"   4";"8.287e+01";"4.270e+01";"1.052e+01"
"   5";"8.747e+01";"4.081e+01";"1.118e+01"
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, ignore chars={"}]
  {data-export-scientific.csv}\myLoadedTable

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    my numeric col/.style={
      sci, sci zerofill, sci sep align, precision=2, sci 10e,
      column name={$y_{#1}$}
    },
    every column/.code={
      \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol>0\relax
        \pgfkeysalso{my numeric col/.expanded={\pgfplotstablecol}}
      \fi
    },
    columns/x/.style={column name={$x$}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{\myLoadedTable}
  \caption{My table data}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[color=blue, only marks] table[x=x, y=y1] {\myLoadedTable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{My plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]